# How to convert firestore query response to json using python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have written the following piece of code:

```
places_ref = db_client.collection(u'places')
doc = places_ref.where (u'city_name', u'==', 'paris').get()
print(doc)
```

The console output is:

```
<generator object Query.get at 0x10d6736d8>
```

If I try this:

```
print(u'Document data: {}'.format(doc.to_dict()))
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

How do I convert the query result to a dictionary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The returned value from firestore is a generator containing many documents. Looking at the [firestore docs](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/) it looks like the following is what you want,

```
my_dict = { el.id: el.to_dict() for el in doc }
```

Comment: It returned only one document but this solved my problem. I am not sure how.

Comment: @AineshPatidar You were attempting to call to_dict on the generator. If you look at the firestore docs again you'll see that they call to_dict on the objects returned by the generator.