# How to fix "Query' object has no attribute 'to_dict" error in python?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've created a cloud function to fetch data from firestore on a particular condition. I've successfully fetched data from firestore but, the data I received from firestore is in "Query Object". How can I convert this Query object into dictionary type?

I've tried `.to_dict()` function to convert it but, it gave me an error,

> Error: function crashed. Details: 'Query' object has no attribute
>   'to_dict'

I've also tried this visit:
[How to convert firestore query response to json using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984107/how-to-convert-firestore-query-response-to-json-using-python)     but,it didn't work.

```
insights = db.collection('GA_data').where('artist_id','==',request_json['artist_id'])
    insights = insights.to_dict() 
    print(insights)
```

Here's my `request_json`,

```
{'artist_id': #some_number}
```

My expected result is,

```
{
"artist_id" : #some_number,
"avgTimeOnPage" : "0.0",
"bouncerate" : "0.0",
"date" : "#some_date",
"newUsers"  : "0",
"pageviews" : "0",
"sessionDuration" : "0.0",
"slug" : "#some_slug",
"users" : "0" 
}
```

But my real output is :

```
Query object : 
google.cloud.firestore_v1.query.Query object at 0x2a5f28059438
```

And, after `.to_dict()` function :

> Error: function crashed. Details: 'Query' object has no attribute
>   'to_dict'

Answer (score 1):

You have to append `stream()` to your `query` and then use a for loop to get the data from each document your query may return, in your case you are expecting only one, I guess, but your query may have more than one document.
Then your code could be something like this:

```
insights = db.collection('GA_data').where('artist_id', '==', request_json['artist_id']
for document in insights.stream():
    print(document.to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Admin SDK Python API for the Firestore [Query](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/query.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.query.Query) class does not include a `to_dict()` method.

You could use the [`on_snapshot(callback)`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/query.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.query.Query.on_snapshot) method as in the following example, and then call `to_dict()` on the document:

```
from google.cloud import firestore_v1

db = firestore_v1.Client()
query_ref = db.collection('GA_data').where('artist_id','==',request_json['artist_id'])

def on_snapshot(docs, changes, read_time):
    for doc in docs:
        print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))

# Watch this query
query_watch = query_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)

# Terminate this watch
query_watch.unsubscribe()
```